# setting initial values for more then one form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have looked at some examples but none of them have worked for me.

What i have is List of Locations and the user has the choice to add them to a group. First step is he gives the group a name. And then he can choose from the locations which are already in the database, to add them to the group name.

To put it simple i want to loop  3 form elements for each location, and attach  initial values for each location, so it can be stored inside a group.

**This is what i want to see:**

```
<form> 

<input type="text" label="group_name">

First Location
<input type="hidden" value="street_name">
<input type="hidden" value="location_name">
<input type="checkbutton"> 

Second location
<input type="hidden" value="street_name2">
<input type="hidden" value="location_name2">
<input type="checkbutton"> 


and so on

<input type="submit" value="Create this Group">

</form>
```

**I have tried it like this:**

Froms.py is currently missing the check input for True and False.
FORMS.py:

```
class GroupAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    groupname = forms.CharField(label='',widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'rows': '4', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    page_name = forms.CharField(label='' ,widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'rows': '4', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    page_street =  forms.CharField(label='' ,widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'rows': '4', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta: 
        model = GroupManagement
        fields = ['groupname', 'page_name', 'page_street']
```

**VIEW:**

```
def page_groups(request):
email =request.user.email
locationdata = LocationData.objects.filter(email=email).values_list(
    'id',
    'name',
    'street',
    'postal_code',
    'tel',  
    'website',
    'description',
    'fb_page_id'
    )

form = []

for items in locationdata:

    name = items[1]
    form = GroupAddForm(request.POST or None, initial={"page_name": name})

print(form)

context = {
'locationdata': locationdata,
'form': form,
}

return render(request, 'page_groups.html', context)
```

**OR in the Template:**

```
 <form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
                                    {% for items in locationdata %}
                                        {{items.1}}
                                        {{form.fields.page_name.value|default:items.1}}
                                        {{form}}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </form>
```

Inside the View only the last element is attached to the form.
The initial Value inside the Template doesn't work at all.

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to do. I only see one form. Where are you trying to set initial values for more then one form? Post some more of your code.

Comment: The Loop creates a Form for each Location. (For item in Locationdata)

Comment: That's still one form. It's within one <form> element.

Comment: Yes that is because you just push a checkbutton which Location should be added and then you push the submit button. There are the same elements in the form for each location but each location has a different id.

Comment: Please post your GroupAddForm and full view. We need to see more then what you've shown.

Comment: Updated the question, with what i want to see maybe it's more easy to understand that way.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself.

```
for items in locationdata:

    name = items[1]
    form = GroupAddForm(request.POST or None, initial={"page_name": name})
    forms.append(form)


    <form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
     {% for items in forms %}
       {{items}}

     {% endfor %}
     </form>
```